# Second Max Date by ID

Tags: sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
ID          Date
123        2/1/2017
123        4/1/2017 
123        6/5/2017 
123        7/8/2017
456        3/8/2017
456        3/9/2017 
456        3/10/2017
```

Dates are in American format.
I want to pull a list of IDs, with the SECOND max date. So i would like the results to be:

```
ID         Date
123       6/5/2017 
456       3/9/2017
```

I do not know how to do this. I have googled, but with no avail. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have tried this, but its not working

```
select *
from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by DATE  desc ) as 'rowNum', ID, DATE
    from table1 ) withRowNum 
where rowNum = 2
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Column Date's data type?

Comment: Your sql is working with sql-server, i have tested it

Comment: Your query should work.

Comment: whats wrong in your result?

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server:

If your dates are `varchar`, and your current date format is not `mdy` then you could use [**`set dateformat`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) e.g.

```
set dateformat mdy;
select *
from (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (
             partition by ID 
             order by convert(date,DATE)  desc
           ) as 'rowNum', ID, DATE
    from table1 ) withRowNum 
where rowNum = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for this!I figured it out